# Ubuntu with python 3.7 installed by default with fresh install

Tags: python, python3

I need to have ubuntu to have python 3.7 installed by default on a fresh installation. I download 18.04 with python 3.6 default and 20 with 3.8. Is there a version in between with python 3.7?

Comment: FYI: Releases between 18.04 & 20.04 are now all EOL   (*they weren't LTS releases*)

Comment: Do you know which version between 18.04 and 20.04 does have python 3.7 installed by default?

Comment: As stated they are off-topic on this site.  (*the answer to your question is yes; 3.7.5 can still be seen on packages.ubu... if you look*)   But why ask?  Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* so if you know when the version of something was released, it's pretty easy to predict (with a pretty good certainty) when it'll hit Debian & Ubuntu (the Ubuntu release being super-easy to pick!)

Answer (score 2):

Simple Answer : Ubuntu 19.04 and Ubuntu 19.10 come with Python 3.7 as default Python version.

Comment: Both Ubuntu versions are EOL.

Comment: As @KKPatel says, both of those Ubuntu versions are EOL and should not be used. If you really need that runtime, you could use LXD on a supported version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it installed by default or just the ability to install it?  Using the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) is the defacto standard way of installing "other" Python versions on Ubuntu.  To install Python 3.7, simply do `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && sudo apt update && apt install python3.7` on any currently supported Ubuntu release.

As others have pointed out, no currently supported version of Ubuntu has Python 3.7 out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only Ubuntu releases to have had Python 3.7 as the default install are now end-of-life, I would suggest using a Python version manager such as `PyEnv`. This is a tool that allows you to install and use multiple Python versions and switch between them.

Installation is a little involved, but you can find detailed instructions here: [Managing Multiple Python Versions With pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/)

You can also find their [Github page here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [another page with installation instructions here](https://medium.com/@Joachim8675309/installing-pythons-with-pyenv-54cca2196cd3).

The installation will involve setting up a bunch of build dependencies, since `PyEnv` installs its python versions direct from source, and then running an installation script.